# Socket exception cannot handle by try catch

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, server, console-application

I have this console application Asynchronoumus server .
Now my problem is after a day or days the application suddenly crashed.
but i have try catch every method i have,
it seems like that error is not being handled by catch,
After looking on logs on application event viewer i have found this error on the day it crushed.

```
Application: CopyChimpServer.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: 
The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags, 
System.AsyncCallback, System.Object) at CopyChimpServer.Program+<>c__DisplayClass2.<AcceptCallback>b__0()
 at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, 
System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, 
System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) 
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

My code

```
 private static void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Socket socket = null;
            string hostname = "";
            string ip_address = "";

            CopyChimpDB copychimp_db = new CopyChimpDB();
            try
            {
                socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
                int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);

                ip_address = (socket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).ToString().Split(':')[0];
                hostname = dict_host[ip_address];

                byte[] dataBuff = new byte[received];
                Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuff, received);

                string message_to_client = "wait";

                if (Convert.ToDouble(Math.Round((DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(dict_cmd_lastsent[hostname])).TotalMinutes, 2)) >= dict_cmd_interval[hostname])
                {
                    var server_command = ServerCommand(hostname);

                    if (server_command.Trim() != "")
                    {
                        //string message_from_client = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuff));
                        message_to_client += "<DriveName>" + dict_drive[hostname] + "</DriveName>";
                        message_to_client += "<ServerCommand>" + ServerCommand(hostname) + "</ServerCommand>";

                        try
                        {
                            copychimp_db.PostCopyChimp("ConnectMachine", hostname, ip_address);
                        }
                        catch (Exception oraex)
                        {
                            ServerLogs(hostname + "--" + oraex.ToString());
                        }
                        dict_cmd_lastsent[hostname] = DateTime.Now;
                        //ServerLogs(hostname + " updated");
                    }


                }

                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message_to_client);
                socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    //_clientSockets.Remove(socket);
                    ServerLogs(hostname + " SocketException! " + ex.Message.ToString());
                    if (hostname != "")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            copychimp_db.PostCopyChimp("DisconnectMachine", hostname, ip_address);
                        }
                        catch (Exception oraex)
                        {
                            ServerLogs(hostname + "--" + oraex.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex_)
                {
                    ServerLogs(hostname + " DisconnectMachine error! " + ex_.ToString());
                }

            }
        }


   private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            string hostname = "";
            try
            {
                CopyChimpDB copychimp_db = new CopyChimpDB();
                Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
                string ip_address = "";

                //hostname checking
                ip_address = (socket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).ToString().Split(':')[0];
                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        hostname = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip_address).HostName;
                    }
                    catch (Exception host_ex)
                    {
                        ServerLogs(ip_address + " GetHostEntry error: " + host_ex.Message.ToString());
                        DataTable dt_ip = copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetHostnameByIpAddress", hostname, ip_address);
                        if (dt_ip.Rows.Count == 1)
                        {
                            hostname = dt_ip.Rows[0]["hostname"].ToString();
                            ServerLogs(ip_address + " GetHostnameByIpAddress : " + hostname);

                        }
                    }
                    DataTable dt_hostname = copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetHostname", hostname, ip_address);
                    hostname = "";
                    if (dt_hostname.Rows.Count == 1)
                    {
                        hostname = dt_hostname.Rows[0]["hostname"].ToString();
                    }
                    else if (dt_hostname.Rows.Count > 1)
                    {
                        ServerLogs(hostname + " GetHostname error: Returns more than 1 row.");
                    }

                    if (hostname != "")
                    {

                        if (!_clientSockets.Contains(socket))
                        {
                            dict_host[ip_address] = hostname;
                            _clientSockets.Add(socket);

                            copychimp_db.PostCopyChimp("ConnectMachine", hostname, ip_address);
                            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            dict_cmd_interval[hostname] = Convert.ToDouble(copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetInterval", hostname, ip_address).Rows[0]["interval"].ToString());
                            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            dict_cmd_lastsent[hostname] = Convert.ToDateTime(copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetLastUpdate", hostname, ip_address).Rows[0]["lastupdate"]);
                            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            dict_drive[hostname] = copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetDriveName", hostname, ip_address).Rows[0]["drive_name"].ToString();
                            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            thread = new Thread(() =>
                            {
                                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
                            });
                            thread.Start();

                            ServerLogs(hostname + " connected");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception oraex)
                {
                    ServerLogs(hostname + "--" + oraex.ToString());
                }
                _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ServerLogs("AcceptCallback SocketException " + hostname + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to avoid this error or to catch this error?
Would a seperate try catch on BeginReceive will be the answer?

Comment: The following line of code is wrong :  _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);  You do not need to BeginAccept in the Accept method.  See msdn examples : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples  The example are for sockets but you can substitute any class that inherits the socket like TCPClient.

Comment: i think that's not the reason of the application crash, if it is wronng the application should stop at the first time,

Comment: It is probably creating a memory leak which eventually causes the crash.