# Socket Begin Receiving Error crash whole application even with a try/catch

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, server, console

I have this console application written in c# running as service on the server. It can run sucessfully for a days and many connections but at some points the service crash with this exception on Windows event viewer.

```
Application: CopyChimpServer.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: 
The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags, 
System.AsyncCallback, System.Object) at CopyChimpServer.Program+<>c__DisplayClass2.<AcceptCallback>b__0()
 at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, 
System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean) at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, 
System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object) 
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

my code is this with many try catch to hadle it but did not work,

```
 private static void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Socket socket = null;
            string hostname = "";
            string ip_address = "";

            CopyChimpDB copychimp_db = new CopyChimpDB();
            try
            {
                socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
                int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);

                ip_address = (socket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).ToString().Split(':')[0];
                hostname = dict_host[ip_address];

                byte[] dataBuff = new byte[received];
                Array.Copy(_buffer, dataBuff, received);

                string message_to_client = "wait";

                if (Convert.ToDouble(Math.Round((DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(dict_cmd_lastsent[hostname])).TotalMinutes, 2)) >= dict_cmd_interval[hostname])
                {
                    var server_command = ServerCommand(hostname);

                    if (server_command.Trim() != "")
                    {
                        //string message_from_client = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuff));
                        message_to_client += "<DriveName>" + dict_drive[hostname] + "</DriveName>";
                        message_to_client += "<ServerCommand>" + ServerCommand(hostname) + "</ServerCommand>";

                        try
                        {
                            copychimp_db.PostCopyChimp("ConnectMachine", hostname, ip_address);
                        }
                        catch (Exception oraex)
                        {
                            ServerLogs(hostname + "--" + oraex.ToString());
                        }
                        dict_cmd_lastsent[hostname] = DateTime.Now;
                        //ServerLogs(hostname + " updated");
                    }


                }

                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message_to_client);
                socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
                //socket.BeginReceive(_buffer,0,_buffer.Length,SocketFlags.None,new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack),)
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    //_clientSockets.Remove(socket);
                    ServerLogs(hostname + " SocketException! " + ex.Message.ToString());
                    if (hostname != "")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            copychimp_db.PostCopyChimp("DisconnectMachine", hostname, ip_address);
                        }
                        catch (Exception oraex)
                        {
                            ServerLogs(hostname + "--" + oraex.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex_)
                {
                    ServerLogs(hostname + " DisconnectMachine error! " + ex_.ToString());
                }

            }
        }

  private static Thread thread;
        private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            string hostname = "";
            try
            {
                CopyChimpDB copychimp_db = new CopyChimpDB();
                Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
                string ip_address = "";

                //hostname checking
                ip_address = (socket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).ToString().Split(':')[0];
                try
                {
                    try
                    {
                        hostname = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip_address).HostName;
                    }
                    catch (Exception host_ex)
                    {
                        ServerLogs(ip_address + " GetHostEntry error: " + host_ex.Message.ToString());
                        DataTable dt_ip = copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetHostnameByIpAddress", hostname, ip_address);
                        if (dt_ip.Rows.Count == 1)
                        {
                            hostname = dt_ip.Rows[0]["hostname"].ToString();
                            ServerLogs(ip_address + " GetHostnameByIpAddress : " + hostname);

                        }
                    }
                    DataTable dt_hostname = copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetHostname", hostname, ip_address);
                    hostname = "";
                    if (dt_hostname.Rows.Count == 1)
                    {
                        hostname = dt_hostname.Rows[0]["hostname"].ToString();
                    }
                    else if (dt_hostname.Rows.Count > 1)
                    {
                        ServerLogs(hostname + " GetHostname error: Returns more than 1 row.");
                    }

                    if (hostname != "")
                    {

                        if (!_clientSockets.Contains(socket))
                        {
                            dict_host[ip_address] = hostname;
                            _clientSockets.Add(socket);

                            copychimp_db.PostCopyChimp("ConnectMachine", hostname, ip_address);
                            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            dict_cmd_interval[hostname] = Convert.ToDouble(copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetInterval", hostname, ip_address).Rows[0]["interval"].ToString());
                            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            dict_cmd_lastsent[hostname] = Convert.ToDateTime(copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetLastUpdate", hostname, ip_address).Rows[0]["lastupdate"]);
                            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            dict_drive[hostname] = copychimp_db.GetCopyChimp("GetDriveName", hostname, ip_address).Rows[0]["drive_name"].ToString();
                            /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                            thread = new Thread(() =>
                            {
                                socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
                            });
                            thread.Start();

                            ServerLogs(hostname + " connected");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception oraex)
                {
                    ServerLogs(hostname + "--" + oraex.ToString());
                }
                _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ServerLogs("AcceptCallback SocketException " + hostname + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

I did search online about socket exeption programming but cant find anything related to this particular call stack and the process terminating.
I've been stock on this for a week ,I have no contact on the developer who made this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you asking the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58495447/4648586) previously?

Comment: Your code contains two calls to BeginReceive. You only put try/catch around one of them.

Comment: The call to BeginReceive in the second function is in a different thread, you have to catch the exception in that thread, not in the function that creates the thread.

Comment: the problem is the one in the `new Thread`; threads have their entire own call context - the `catch` does not apply

Comment: iakobski and John Wu is that that reason of the application crash? because the application is sucessfully running for a days , so if it gets on the BeginReceive on the place time it will trow already an exception and the app will not run for a days

Comment: @MarcGravell is that going to resolve the problem , because the application is running seucessfully for a day so if that's the reason it shoukd be crushing at the first time it read that code part

Comment: @AlmostDone it *is* the problem, yes; not every call is destined to throw a socket exception...

Comment: You may add a try catch block around your `BeginReceive` and diagnose exception's `ErrorCode`. That should probably move you in a way to the reason of the exception.

Comment: how can i test my program on my pc?